# Why do the conditions in this for loop multiply and divide by two (when I use >>= in for loop)

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I was practicing some sample in C++ I found a program where the code is given below:

```
unsigned int num;
int c = 0;
cin >> num;
for (; num; num <<= 1)
{
    if (num & 1)
    {
        c++;
    }
}
cout << "c : " << c << endl;
```

So I have following questions in mind:

1. In this for loop condition, the second parameter is `num` — what is the significance keeping it as `num`; why not any condition like `num<29` or may be some other value?
2. Whereas the third parameter is `z=num <<= 1`, here I had kept `z` to do some debugging to know the value obtained on this condition, but I found that it just doubles when the operator is `>>=` and halves when it is `<<=`. Why this behavior?
3. In the if condition we have `if (int y=num & 1)`. I am not able to understand what it does with  `& 1`?

I tried to understand it by debugging but I want to know clear explanation of these three questions so that's why I wanted to ask experts.

Comment: c/c++ is not a language

Comment: This is no C code. And - as @awesomeyi already stated - there is no language C/C++.

Comment: Please get a C or C++ book. These are very basic operations you have to understand. And there is much more interesting stuff in books

Comment: (1) The test `if (num)` is equivalent to `if (num != 0)`. (2) I think you have your observations back-to-front. `num >>= 1` will divide by 2; `num <<= 1` will multiply by 2. (3) The `y & 1` selects the least significant bit of `y`. Infelicity: You don't show the declaration of `z`, and you don't use the value of either `y` or `z`. Infelicity: because the code shown is left shifting num, the maximum value in `c` will be `1` (if the entered number is odd); otherwise, it is zero. That's because the left shift always inserts a zero in the least significant bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since `num` is an `unsigned int`, the condition `num` in the `for` loop refers to it being `true`, or anything greater than `0`. So the loop runs until `num` becomes 0 or less.
2. `<<` is known as the left-shift operator, while `>>` is the right-shift operator. I'll better leave it for you to understand how they work. Read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work) to understand them better.
   Note: `z` is unused
3. `&` is the [bitwise AND operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).
   Note: `y` is unused too.

Answer (score 6):

For third,`&` is a bitwise `AND` operator. Doing `if (int y=num & 1)` checks if the last bit (least significant bit) of the number is set. If it is set, the number is odd, and if it is not set, it is even. However, y is trash here, `if (num & 1)` is enough for the checking.

Comment: thanks for the 3rd point answer, yes i know y is trash there, I had kept it for debugging purpose in order to know the changing values of if condition

Comment: and another one here :)